# How to set output to be EMPTY, currently shows a ROW

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, output, is-empty

Here is a FonzSummary to assist in understanding the issue -- Correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3mb3.jpg, Incorrect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK6Rw.jpg

Issue:
I'm having some issues with showing empty output... I ***want*** the output to reflect absolutely nothing if there are no results, but so far I have been unsuccessful.

```
SET @AddedOutput =
CASE WHEN @AddedList IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE 'Kids added to Santas Naughty List'+@AddedNames
END

SET @RemovedOutput =
CASE WHEN @RemovedList IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE 'Kids removed from Santas Naughty List'+@RemovedNames
END

--Final Output
SELECT CASE
WHEN @AddedOutput IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 0 NULL) 
ELSE @AddedOutPut END as 'List Changes'
UNION
SELECT CASE
WHEN @RemovedOutput IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 0 NULL) 
ELSE @RemovedOutput END as 'List Changes'
```

To further complicate things, once I added (Select TOP 0 NULL) to my proc, the valid results no longer work! Why does this make it attempt to convert to Int? I know the results aren't going to be Int!

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SantaList_TEST, Line 72
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Kids added 
to Santas Naughty List 27065, 28538, 28539' to data type int.
```

Comment: Tag dbms used! That doesn't look like ANSI SQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two subqueries each returning one row.  The output will have one or two rows.  One method would be to do:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT @AddedOutPut as ListChanges
      UNION
      SELECT @RemovedOutput as ListChange
     ) t
WHERE ListChanges IS NOT NULL;
```

The `THEN (SELECT TOP 0 NULL)` in your `CASE` statement is a valiant attempt to try to get no rows.  However, the `FROM` clause (along with the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `FETCH`/`TOP` clauses) really determines what rows are being returned.  The `(SELECT TOP 0 NULL)` is being used as a scalar subquery.  If it doesn't return anything, then SQL puts in `NULL`, hence the radical simplification of your query.

Also, I doubt `UNION` is really needed in this case.  It incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  As a matter of habit, it is better to learn to use `UNION ALL`, unless you really want to incur the overhead.

Comment: Gordon, I really appreciate the time you took to explain that - It demonstrates a much more eloquent solution that will definitely help me moving forward.